# Concatenated Dynamic SQL Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table of shipping data:

| Tracking # | Zone | Service | PackageType | PackageWeight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | 4 | DHLPPE | CUSTOM | 1.5 |
| 9876543210 | 2 | F02 | CUSTOM | 2 |

And a table of shipping markup costs that extends on forever in both directions, many zones, many different services and weight breaks.

| Service | PackageType | WeightLow | WeightHigh | Zone_1 | Zone_2 | Zone_3 | Zone_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DHLPPE | CUSTOM | 0 | 1 | 3.75 | 4.5 | 3.45 | 2.2 |
| DHLPPE | CUSTOM | 1.01 | 2 | 3.85 | 4.6 | 3.55 | 2.3 |
| DHLPPE | CUSTOM | 2.01 | 3 | 4.5 | 3.4 | 1.2 | 7.32 |
| F02 | CUSTOM | 0 | 1 | 2.2 | 7.6 | 4.33 | 1.23 |
| F02 | CUSTOM | 1.01 | 2 | 3.2 | 5.6 | 2.33 | 1.43 |

...

How do I find the markup charge for each shipment by dynamically querying the concatenated 'Zone_' + @Zone in the second table?

So I am looking for this result where MarkupValue would be the corresponding zone field value

| Tracking # | Service | MarkupValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | DHLPPE | 2.3 |
| 9876543210 | F02 | 5.6 |

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried. And for an easy to answer question add your sample data as DDL+DML. And why have you tagged stored procedures? You don't mention that in your question, is it relevant at all?

Comment: that is a bad schema, you should probably normalize your data.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to modify the case statement according to the number of Zones you have in the table**

```
CREATE TABLE #ShipingData (TrackingNo VARCHAR(15), zone INT, service VARCHAR(10), packageType VARCHAR(10), PackageWeight FLOAT)

INSERT INTO #ShipingData(    TrackingNo,    zone,    service,    packageType,    PackageWeight)
        SELECT    '1234567890', 4, 'Dhlppe', 'Custom', 1.5   
UNION   SELECT    '9876543210', 2, 'F02', 'Custom', 2

CREATE TABLE #ShipingMarkupCost (service VARCHAR(10), packageType VARCHAR(10), WeightLow FLOAT, WeightHigh FLOAT, Zone_1 FLOAT, Zone_2 FLOAT, Zone_3 FLOAT, Zone_4 FLOAT)

INSERT INTO #ShipingMarkupCost ( service,    packageType,    WeightLow,    WeightHigh,    Zone_1,    Zone_2,    Zone_3,    Zone_4)
  SELECT   'Dhlppe',  'Custom',  0.0,  1.0, 3.75, 4.5, 3.45, 2.2 
UNION SELECT   'Dhlppe',  'Custom',  1.01, 2.0, 3.85, 4.6, 3.55, 2.3 
UNION SELECT   'Dhlppe',  'Custom',  2.01, 3.0, 4.5, 3.4, 1.2, 7.32 
UNION SELECT   'F02',     'Custom',  0.0,  1.0, 2.2, 7.6, 4.33, 1.23 
UNION SELECT   'F02',     'Custom',  1.01, 2.0, 3.2, 5.6, 2.33, 1.43

SELECT * FROM #ShipingData
SELECT * FROM #ShipingMarkupCost

SELECT a.TrackingNo, a.service, a.packageType, a.PackageWeight, b.WeightLow, b.WeightHigh,
    CASE a.zone 
        WHEN 4 THEN b.Zone_4
        WHEN 3 THEN b.Zone_3
        WHEN 2 THEN b.Zone_2
        WHEN 1 THEN b.Zone_1
    END MarkUpValue
FROM #ShipingData a INNER JOIN #ShipingMarkupCost b ON b.packageType = a.packageType AND b.service = a.service
WHERE a.PackageWeight BETWEEN b.WeightLow AND b.WeightHigh


DROP TABLE #ShipingData 
DROP TABLE #ShipingMarkupCost`
```

**Result :**

| TrackingNo | service | MarkupValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | Dhlppe | 2.3 |
| 9876543210 | F02 | 5.6 |

Comment: Thank you, this is what I ended up doing, however there are 15 zones for the domestic table, then many more for international. I was thinking there has to be a 'better' way using dynamic sql or stored procedure

Comment: Consider changing your table design then, Down the line, if you are trying to adding more zones, you should NOT go and add columns.

Answer (score -1):

select sh.Tracking# , serv.service ,
COALESCE(SUM(zone), 0) FROM shipping) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Zone_1), 0) FROM Service) as MarkupValue
from shipping  sh
join Service serv
on sh.Service = serv.Service

Comment: That quite obviously doesn't work, the subqueries are not correlated, and any case you have some syntax errors